# Picking out pairs from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am working on exercise 16 from SQL-EX.com

```
Find the pairs of PC models having identical speeds and RAM.
As a result, each resulting pair is shown only once, i.e. (i, j) but not (j, i).
Result set: model with higher number, model with lower number, speed, and RAM.
```

I used the following query

```
SELECT B.code, B.model AS BM, A.code, A.model, A.speed, A.ram 
FROM PC A
JOIN PC B
ON A.speed = B.speed AND A.ram = B.ram
WHERE A.model <> B.model
ORDER BY B.model ASC
```

[image]

How do I retrieve only the pairs where `BM` is higher than `model`?

Comment: That site seems to discourage publishing the exercises or working on them jointly: http://sql-ex.com/register.php

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<>`, use `<`:

```
SELECT
    a.model,
    b.model,
    a.speed,
    a.ram
FROM PC a
INNER JOIN PC b
    ON b.speed = a.speed
    AND b.ram = a.ram
    AND b.model < a.model
```

Comment: Ugghhhh... sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to catch that.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
WHERE A.model <> B.model
```

To this:

```
WHERE A.model > B.model
```

You also need to select the correct columns, but getting that WHERE expression right was the hard part.